# How can you measure the space that a set of documents takes up (in bytes) in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

What I would like to do is figure out how much space in bytes a certain set of documents takes up. E.g. something like:

`collection.stuff.stats({owner: someOwner}, {sizeInBytes: 1})`

Where the first parameter is a query, and the second is like a projection of the statistics you want calculated.

I read that there's a `bsonsize` function you can use to measure the size of a single document. I'm wondering if maybe I could use that along with the aggregation methods to calculate the size of a search. But if I was going to do that, I'd want to know how bsonsize works. How does it work? Is it expensive to run?

Are there other options for measuring the size of data in mongo?

Comment: What "size" measure are you looking for: size on disk or size of documents? Are documents in this collection fairly homogenous, or will the size be highly variable?

Comment: I know how to count the number of documents, that's easy. I'm looking for bytes here.

Answer (score 1):

One perhaps "quick and dirty" way to find this would be to assign your results to a cursor, then insert that result into a new collection and call `db.collection.stats` on it. It would look like this in the shell:

```
var myCursor = db.collection.find({key:value});
while(myCursor.hasNext()) {
    db.resultColl.insert(myCursor.next())
}

db.resultColl.stats();
```

Which should return the information on the subset of documents

Comment: I think you missed the gist of the question, which is how to measure the space taken up by a set of documents matching a query. The db or collection stats() information applies to all documents in that scope.

Comment: Stennie, this would in fact do what I want (he's putting all the docs from a query into a new collection). Problem is, this is a *very* dirty way to do it. This would be very inefficient, and I'd like a way to do it that doesn't involve copying around a lot of data.